# How to show Delivery methods (Shipping Method) in Magento product page

Tags: php, magento, web, e-commerce, shopping-cart

I have a magneto Store and I have a custom requirement.

I have my own templet and I need to display Delivery Methods on product page.

Normally shipping methods available on a Checkout page. But I need to add it on Product page.

Please help me or guide me to do this.

Many thanks
Umanda

Answer (score 0):

afaik are the shipping methods are connected to the address. No address - no shipping methods.

but if you look into `Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Shipping_Method_Available` you could read all the data from

```
Mage::getStoreConfig('carriers/*/title');
```

so just call

```
Mage::getStoreConfig('carriers');
```

loop over all carriers, collect the titles and check wether they are activated or not.

And have a look into

```
app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Block/Onepage/Shipping/Method/Available.php:40
Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Shipping_Method_Available::getShippingRates()
```